# How do i format these int values to print as money. (Slot Machine program)

Tags: java, format

I'm  making a program for class. It is supposed to be a slot machine. You get a bet from the user and if they match numbers, they get a reward. We have to use all integers, but all numbers have to be printed as money such as $10.00 for 10 .In the first if statement is where I tried to format it but an error came up. Please help and if you see any other problem,s please point them out.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SlotMachine {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int slot1, slot2, slot3;
     Random generator = new Random();
     int balance = 10;
     int bet;
     do {
         System.out.println("Enter your bet");
         bet = input.nextInt();
     } while (bet < 0 || bet > balance);
     while (bet != 0) {
         slot1 = generator.nextInt(10);
         slot2 = generator.nextInt(10);
         slot3 = generator.nextInt(10);
         slot1 = 3;
         slot2 = 3;
         slot3 = 3; 
         System.out.println("Your numbers are " + slot1 + " " + slot2 + " " + slot3);
         if ((slot1 == slot2 && slot1==slot3 && slot2 == slot3)&& slot1 >0)
         {
             int winnings = (slot1 + 1)*bet;
             System.out.printf("Your winnings are: %.2f"+ winnings);
             balance = balance - bet + winnings;
             System.out.printf("Your new balance is: %.2f "+ balance);

         }
         if (slot1 == slot2 || slot1 == slot3 || slot2 == slot3)
         {
             if(slot1 == slot2 || slot1 == slot3 && slot1 >0)
             {
                 int winnings = (slot1 * bet)/2;
                 System.out.println("Your winnings are " + winnings);
                 balance = balance - bet + winnings;
                 System.out.println("Your new balance is " + balance);
             }
             else if (slot2 == slot3)
             {
                 int winnings = (slot2 * bet)/2;
                 System.out.println("Your winnings are " + winnings);
                 balance = balance - bet + winnings;
                 System.out.println("Your new balance is " + balance);
             }


         }
         else
         {
            int winnings = 0;
            balance = balance - bet + winnings;
            System.out.println("Your balance is " + balance);
         }
        if (balance > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your bet");
            bet = input.nextInt();
        }
        else
        {
            bet = 0;
        }

     }
     int winnings = balance - bet;
     System.out.println(winnings);
     System.out.println(balance);
     }
}
```

Comment: If you're only formatting `int` values, why not `"$" + intvar + ".00"`?

Comment: This post has nothing to do with javascript, if you remove that tag, you should get a better answer sooner.

Comment: Your question is specifically about formatting the output, so it would be useful to reduce your code sample to just the relevant parts. [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: by the way, %.2f will only work for float values. that is probably the error you got. please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

first, you dont need to do

```
(slot1 == slot2 && slot1==slot3 && slot2 == slot3)
```

just

```
(slot1 == slot2 && slot2 == slot3)
```

and further, if you are sure that all numbers involved are integers and also that we only need to display .00 at the end, then just do

```
System.out.println("Your new balance is: $"+ balance + ".00");
```

since we are only adding, i doubt that there will be a fractional part

finally, if you still want to use printf, you need to convert int to float

```
System.out.printf("Your winnings are: %.2f", (float)winnings);
```

note that in your code you were using the + instead of ,

that is used in println or print. not in printf